# I can't deduce the function behind this, expert assistance is required

Tags: html, css, layout, menu

This little code that I've copied from a tutorial website explaining how to create a pure CSS horizontal menu, just when I thought I've finally understood how it worked, I discovered this thing and basically now I'm trying to reflect on all the things that I've learned in CSS, I'm stuck.

So basically the code is like this, CSS.

```
#nav, .nav, #nav .nav li { margin:0px; padding:0px; }
#nav li {float:left; display:inline; cursor:pointer; list-style:none; padding:0px 10px 0px 10px; border:1px #000 solid; 
position:relative;}
#nav li ul.first {left:-1px; top:100%;}

li, li a {color:#000; text-decoration:none;}
#nav .nav li { width:100%; text-indent:10px; line-height:30px; margin-right:10px; border-top:1px #000 solid; 
border-bottom:1px #000 solid; border-left:none; border-right:none; background:#fff;}
#nav li a {display:block; width:inherit; height:inherit;}

ul.nav { display:none; }
#nav li:hover > a, #nav li:hover { color:#fff; background:#000; }
li:hover > .nav { display:block; position:absolute; width:200px; top:-2px; left:50%; z-index:1000; border:1px #000 solid; }
li:hover { position:relative; z-index:2000; }
```

and the html,

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>Menu 1
        <ul class="nav first">
            <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
            <li>Menu 2</li>
            <li>Menu 3</li>
            <li>Menu 4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
    <li>Menu 3</li>
    <li>Menu 4</li>
</ul>
```

Now this is where the problem begins, in the CSS, on the 9th line, yes, at the 
`li:hover > .nav` part, when I change it to `#nav li:hover > .nav`, the drop down menu just messes up, it won't behave like it should have, and I'm trying to uncover how a simple `#nav` can mess the layout, I've come up with some theories, but I can't seem to prove them since they contradict with some of the things that I've learned, I really need somehow who can explain this to me, I'm going nuts!

If anyone, please, thank you.

Comment: `position:relativea;` typo

Comment: Ok, but I've tried just now, and regardless of whether it is a typo or not, it still messes up. T_T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```css
#nav li ul.first {left:-1px; top:100%;}
```

And

```css
li:hover > .nav { display:block; position:absolute; width:200px; top:-2px; left:50%; z-index:1000; border:1px #f00 solid; }
```

Since the first line is more specific, its `left` and `top` values will have precedence over those of the latter line. Once you change the latter line to this:

```css
#nav li:hover > .nav { display:block; position:absolute; width:200px; top:-2px; left:50%; z-index:1000; border:1px #f00 solid; }
```

It becomes more specific than the first and gains precedence over the first instead. That's why the positioning changes.

You can read up on this stuff by googling "css precedence", for example: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

Comment: Wow thanks, somehow I've gotten closer to understanding this whole thing. ^_^